# sequelize between operator not working properly

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to do query to get all rows between id 1 to 4.
I am using mySQL and sequelize.
query

`

```
main.test = function(req,res,next)
{
    var param = req.params;
    model.Time.find({
          where:{
            id:{
                $between:[1,4]
            }
         },limit: 10
        }).then(function (time) {

                console.log("Time"+time);
    });

    }
```

`

and getting the result when execute[image]

Need a way solve it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: use findAll(), you're using find() that's why you only get the 1 row as result